# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzb(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)

Tags: android, build.gradle

I'm stuck in my first real-time firebase app. :(
I was making a simple registration app using firebase and but I found a runtime error .  please
remember I'm using **android-studio 2.3**.

**Note-** I've included google-services.json also in the required directory.

Error is [image]

My project-level gradle file is
[image]

**Note:- I think this problem might be----> "due to my  sdk manager .but I dont'know how I check which sdk files are required for android studio 2.3 working with firebase".**

```
                                   or,
```

My app-level gradle file also may contain wrong firebase-auth /firebase-core dependency. please check it below in picture:-

[image]

[image]

Please guide me with pictorial way because this problem is not explained anywhere with a right solution.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: please check also when I included firebase-auth:10.2.1 it gives me error---> Can not resolve this file.               then, I used  firebase-auth:9.4.0

Comment: its a bug they are having, I had a similar issue. try using version 10.2.0 for now.

Comment: I used 10.2.0 &  now my app is insalling into my emulator correcctly but whenever I submit username & password then, it gotta crashed ...nd throw runtime error on logcat window such as-->       com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Invalid Firebase url specified

Comment: please help me :(  I'm totally frustated from 3 days . nothing is working.. And cant start my project :(

Comment: best solution is upgrade your android studio to 2.3 and then use firebase assistent available in tools section . and choose firebase feature and directly connect to that firebase service online..then it'll automatically add /download all dependencies required for that firebase feature and place auto-sync also.. :)

Comment: you can see - [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45905719/no-static-method-zzb-when-user-firebase-database-and-facebook-account-kit) - hope it solve you problem.

Comment: @MahmudurRahman only one solution I found to reinstall the android studio... no one soltion worked for me