# No static method zzb - when user firebase-database and facebook account kit

Tags: java, android, facebook

when using facebook, firebase-database account kit alone both work fine but when I am using both in same time in a project it give error-

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzb(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzac; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac' appears in /data/app/com.neccargo-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes14.dex)`

I am using dependencies-

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.karumi:dexter:4.1.1'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1.1@aar'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.7.0'
    compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.7.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I am stuck about to find solution.

Comment: did u find solution to this problem ?

Comment: yes, i give the answer below. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding firebase core library.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I find my solution after many failure. **In dependencies use those -**

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'
```

and then add `multiDexEnabled true` in `build.gradle`

then add those line in `buildscript`-

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.0.4'
```

in there also add in `allprojects`-

```
maven { 
   url "https://maven.google.com" 
}
```

Then create a class like -

```
public class AppUtils extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext());
    }
}
```

add this class name in `AndroidManifest` like-

```
android:name=".AppUtils"
```

That's the process I overcome that problem.